How use airflow params in helm template
i have sparkApplication.yaml with driver configutation:
 driver:
    cores:  {{.Values.params.driver_cores}}

in my values.yaml file:
  params:
    driver_cores: 1

and after that in CI i tried to set  helm template --set params.driver_cores="\{\{ params.driver_cores \}\}" (i want to use Jinja template to redefine it later during the launch in Airflow )
but i got error :
install.go:222: [debug] Original chart version: ""
install.go:239: [debug] CHART PATH: /builds/sparkjob
Error: YAML parse error on sparkjob/sparkApplication.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: invalid map key: map[interface {}]interface {}{"params.driver_cores":interface {}(nil)}
helm.go:84: [debug] error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: invalid map key: map[interface {}]interface {}{"params.driver_cores":interface {}(nil)}
YAML parse error on sparkjob/templates/sparkApplication.yaml
helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/releaseutil.(*manifestFile).sort
    helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/releaseutil/manifest_sorter.go:146
helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/releaseutil.SortManifests
    helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/releaseutil/manifest_sorter.go:106
helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/action.(*Configuration).renderResources
    helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/action/action.go:168
helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/action.(*Install).RunWithContext
    helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/action/install.go:312
main.runInstall
    helm.sh/helm/v3/cmd/helm/install.go:314
main.newTemplateCmd.func2
    helm.sh/helm/v3/cmd/helm/template.go:95
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).execute
    github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.8.0/command.go:983
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).ExecuteC
    github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.8.0/command.go:1115
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).Execute
    github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.8.0/command.go:1039
main.main
    helm.sh/helm/v3/cmd/helm/helm.go:83
runtime.main
    runtime/proc.go:[27](https://gitlab****/-/jobs/51744#L27)1
runtime.goexit
    runtime/asm_amd64.s:1695

BUT when i used --set params.driver_cores="0{{ params.driver_cores }}" with 0 before brackets it work, i think helm have bug which not allowed symbols '{{' after rendering in begin of value,
driver:
    cores:  {{params.driver_cores}}

allowed
 driver:
    cores:  0{{params.driver_cores}}

!!!BUT  0{{params.driver_cores}} will octal number, not decimal, and its not suit for me
Output of helm version:3.15.2
Output of kubectl version:1.30.2
Cloud Provider/Platform: Gitlab Ci,  image:  name: alpine/k8s:1.30.2
How i can render helm template and keep some values like??:
driver:
    cores:  {{params.driver_cores}}

i cant use quotes because spark need integer value
driver:
    cores:  "{{params.driver_cores}}"


Can you try type conversion from string to int   https://helm.sh/docs/chart_best_practices/values/    in your case: {{ int .Values.params.driver_cores}}
